# Why is this in static context?

Tags: c#

```
public T Prop = new Ctor(Method);

private K Method(U controller, V request);
```

I get that it can't access `Method` here, because `Method` is required to be `static`. Why is this? `Prop` is not `static`.

**Update:** Here's the actual signature:

```
public DataSource(Func<ControllerBase, AjaxDataTable.Request, Result> dataSelector)
```

And this is how the method used to be:

```
public AjaxDataTable<SourcesViewModel.Source.Channel>.DataSource AjaxData =
    new AjaxDataTable<SourcesViewModel.Source.Channel>.DataSource(OnSelectData);
```

This wasn't an issue because I didn't need to reference `this`, so when I added `this` and it didn't compile anymore, (the field wasn't mine to begin with, someone else had done it like that, so don't hate me for that). I changed it to the following:

```
private AjaxDataTable<SourcesViewModel.Source.Channel>.DataSource ajaxData;
public AjaxDataTable<SourcesViewModel.Source.Channel>.DataSource AjaxData
{
    get
    {
        if (ajaxData == null)
        {
            ajaxData =
                new AjaxDataTable<SourcesViewModel.Source.Channel>
                    .DataSource(OnDataSelector);
        }
        return ajaxData;
    }
}
```

But then the `ajaxData` private field would always be `null`, which makes the data table be instanced again every time (this is appended into a concurrent dictionary, which causes an `Exception` on a duplicate key). I want to know how assigning to a field that doesn't reference `this` works. Does that create something that is reused across all instances of an `object`?

Comment: Why are you passing a method as a parameter? Is that really what you intend to do? Or do you just mean to show that you're calling it and using the result in the constructor?

Comment: Yes, it's a lambda expression.

Comment: @abelenky that's the point. The compiler is telling me this is illegal because `Method` is required to be `static`.

Comment: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property `OnSelectData(ControllerBase, Request)'`

Comment: Even if it doesn't compile/run, you should post enough context such that we can see what you are trying to do. For example, what is the signature of `Ctor.ctor` ?

Comment: @Nico pedant point: no, `Method` is not a lambda expression - it is a method group, presumably being used to provide a typed-delegate parameter. A lambda would involve `=>` at some point.

Comment: @Nico: The code you've shown in the property really *should* only create a new `AjaxDataTable` once *per instance of the containing class*, threading issues notwithstanding. Are you sure you're not just using lots of different instances of the containing class?

Comment: @Jon great, then the bug is somewhere else in the code, I just wanted to make sure there wasn't some funky optimization stuff going on here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is due to section 10.5.5.2 of the C# 4 spec, which includes:

> A variable initializer for an instance field cannot reference the instance being created. Thus it is a compile-time error to reference `this` in a variable initializer [...]

You're *effectively* referencing `this`, as your code is equivalent to:

```
public T Prop = new Ctor(this.Method);
```

Now you can argue that this restriction is draconian, but that's a different discussion. Note that you *could* put it into a constructor body:

```
public T Prop;

public Foo()
{
    Prop = new Ctor(Method);
}
```

(I'm assuming you wouldn't *really* have a public field, and that you'd have sensible names, etc :)

Comment: Jon, you are scary sometimes... +1

Comment: @Yuck: To be fair, I did have to consult the spec. I didn't know it off by heart :)

Answer (score 1):

As the compiler tells you, "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property" - so; you can't use a field initializer. Use a constructor instead:

```
public T Prop; // public field? really? a property would be preferable most cases
public YourType() {
    Prop = new Ctor(Method);
}
```